# Create UML Class Diagrams from Code Using EMF in eclipse

Tags: java, php, class, uml, emf

My question is how do generate UML Class Diagrams from a source code using EMF in eclipse?
I'm working on a project and I need this.
the code is writing in PHP. and java

Comment: I don't think it has reverse engineering. [edit] seems I may have been wrong about that http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/462039/

Comment: I know it can reverse Java code, but how about php?